# ezdb file on visual studio?

Tags: .net, database, visual-studio, file, plaintext

I've a EZDB file on Windows, it's a "normal" text file, it can be opened with any text editor. (See image) but at the begining it says EZDB (0xx455A in hex). Some parts are in plain text, but it has other data i think it's the database format.

I look it up, but i can't find **anything** for visual sudio. There are things for PHP and Perl, but this file is generated a desktop app (not sure is VS).

[image: ezdb header]

Has anyone seen this? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a [voidtools "Everything"](http://www.voidtools.com/) uncompressed data file!

"Everyting" is used to locate files and folders by name super-fast. It stores that information in a file named Everything.[MACHINENAME].[USERNAME].db